# Gone to the competition or for the competition

Tags: word-usage

A girl had taken part in a competition. She had to go to another school. Someone asked me "Where is A?". I replied:

> She has **gone to** the competition (or "contest) to school X.
>
> She has **gone for** the contest/competition to school X.

I feel "gone for" sounds more natural. Am I right in thinking so?

Comment: Both ***to*** and ***for*** are perfectly acceptable prepositions for the *first* occurrence in your example, but I would suggest ***at** school* rather than ***to** school* for the second.

Comment: And @FumbleFingers will "to" be more likely or "for"?

Comment: @FumbleFingers Doesn't "go for" usually mean "go to get"? I can accept it if one says "go for the championship".  But "go for the competition" doesn't really make much sense to me.

Comment: So @FumbleFingers will it only be "go to the competition"? (She is a participant.)

Comment: Whether or not something sounds more natural (your question) will depend largely on the person hearing the statement.  The second form is perhaps slightly more correct as "to school X" is *where* she has gone and "for the contest/competition" is *why* she has gone.

Comment: @RobLambden: I'm not sure *any* native speakers would endorse *Pussy cat, pussy cat, where have you been? \ I've been **to visit** the Queen **to London**.* It seems to me if there are two adverbial clauses (one specifying ***where***, the other specifying ***why***), it's only acceptable to use the preposition ***to*** for both if they occur *in that order*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I thought the original was *"Pussy cat, pussy cat, where have you been? I've been to London to visit the Queen."* so the *why* and the *what* are the other way around but I understand the point you are making.  The question is about what sounds *more* natural so I haven't commented on correctness or any other options as it wasn't asked for. In this example I personally think using *for* and *to* and to *in both* sounds clumsy.  I would use *for* and *at* which I would prefer to *to* and *to* -- and in your Pussy cat example I would have *to visit* and *in London*.

Comment: @RobLambden: When I said *in that order*, I was referring to what I'd put in brackets *(**where** followed by **why**)*, not the "deliberately misquoted" mangled nursery rhyme example. I fully accept your point that in *some* contexts, different native speakers will disagree over whether and to what extent any given usage is "natural". But I do think there are some *other* contexts (such as two consecutive instances of ***to***, where one relates to an adverbial "location, direction" element, the other to a "purpose" clause), where we'd all agree that only one sequence really works.

Comment: ...apropos which I'm not sure I'd want to be drawn on whether [*Jack and Jill went **to fetch** a pail of water **up the hill***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jack_and_Jill_(nursery_rhyme)) is actually "ungrammatical" or just "totally non-idiomatic".

Comment: @FumbleFingers - yes when I said I understood the point you were making, I understood that you had deliberately misquoted and why - sorry if that didn't "sound natural" to you (pun intended).  We both agree that our preference is *for* and *at* (which was not one of the options) and I think we also agree that *to* and *to* is less natural. *If* we choose to use *to* for both then I agree that to sound natural we would want to have *where* followed by *why*.

Comment: So @RobLambden are you saying that "She has gone for 
the competition" is better than "She has gone to the competition". Did I get you right? Is there a better way to phrase it?

Comment: And @RobLambden will it be better to use "She has gone for the competition **at** X."? (You said that you'd prefer "at" to "to".)

Comment: @It's about English - there is a slightly different meaning - "to" is where she has gone, and "for" is why she has gone. You might use either in response to a question "Where is A?" even thougn why she has gone doesn't necessarily answer the actual question.  To me saying "She's gone for the competition at X" sounds more natural than saying she's gone for the competition to X.  You can see from the exchange here that using "for" and "to" together doesn't seem right to most people. So (in my opinion) saying "She's gone for the competition at X" is the most natural sounding and complete answer.

Comment: She has gone to x school for the competition.

Answer (score 1):

"There is a slightly different meaning - "to" is where she has gone, and "for" is why she has gone."
"You might use either in response to a question "Where is A?" even though why she has gone doesn't necessarily answer the actual question."  - Rob Lambden

Reviewing each choice:

> She has gone to the competition to school X.

"at school X" would be preferable.

> She has gone to the competition at school X.

Ok

> She has gone for the competition to school X.

"at school X" would be preferable.

> She has gone for the competition at school X.

While other commenters have said this is a good choice, just in my personal opinion it doesn't sound perfect. This would be better :

> She has gone to school X for the competition.

Ok